# JSONB available data type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find out if this is implemented in mysql? I can only find information relating to postgresql.

So, can you use JSONB in mysql or is it just JSON?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The main difference between the `json` and `jsonb` types in Postgres is that the latter is stored in a compressed binary format.  From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), it appears that MySQL's JSON type already has at least some of the behavior of Postgres' `jsonb`:

> The JSON data type provides these advantages over storing JSON-format strings in a string column:
>
> Optimized storage format. JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements. When the server later must read a JSON value stored in this binary format, the value need not be parsed from a text representation. The **binary format** is structured to enable the server to look up subobjects or nested values directly by key or array index without reading all values before or after them in the document.

If I recall correctly, the MySQL JSON functions will still work correctly on JSON text (e.g. stored as `varchar`), so maybe MySQL's analogy to Postgres' `json` would just be storing JSON content as plain text.

Comment: so there is no JSONB type in mysql - just JSON that is a bit like JSONB?

Comment: Yeah...that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: "If I recall correctly, the MySQL JSON functions will still work correctly on JSON text (e.g. stored as varchar)," indeed MySQL's JSON functions requirement it's that the input is valid JSON format

Comment: I did a quick test with JSON vs TEXT type in MySQL 5.7. 100k rows with different JSON objects. Table with TEXT took 2.3GB on disk, while table with JSON took 2.2GB. No big difference there.

Comment: @KasparsFoigts This seems pretty good though, considering that for being able to look up subobjects directly by key, as the docs state, the binary data structure would need at least some additional storage for hashmaps or other kinds of indices.